# Atom eslint не видит tsx

Tags: typescript

такая проблема , атом не показывает ошибки линтера в файлах ts или tsx , через командную строку он находит в них кучу ошибок а в атоме не отображается , файлы js и jsx видит а их нет , в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: а ещё помогает использование VSCode

Answer (score 0):

кто сталкивался с этим , помогла вот эта ссылка https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/1293

Comment: думаю, стоит принять свой ответ как решение.